# Why Woocommerce isn't calculating shipping charges?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am planning to charge multi layered shipping from customer.

What I want:

A customer choose Delivery Location (City).
He/She should be presented with further Regions (Regions Drop Down Menu).
Upon Selecting any Region it should furtehr narrow down block/area/colony.

Delivery needs to be charged on Block/Area/Colony (Area/Colony/Block would get enabled separately based on Regions).

Each area/Block/Colony should have a different shipping charges.

For example Lahore - Agrics is a region.

Upon Selecting Lahore - Agrics, another drop down menu appears having Block A, Block B and Block C.

I want to charge separately based on each Block and here I have conditioned it as 100/150/180 respectively.

I have tried but it's not working. It gets only 50/additional kg (another condition) but not this one.

Can somebody please have a look and see what I am missing?

```
Add custom fields to the checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'add_custom_checkout_fields' );

function add_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id= custom_checkout_field >';
    
    // Delivery Location dropdown
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_location', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Delivery Location'),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => array(
            'lahore'         => __('Lahore', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_location' ));

    // Regions dropdown
    woocommerce_form_field( 'region', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Regions'),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => array(
            'lahore_agrics'              => __('Lahore - Agrics', 'woocommerce' ),
            'lahore_sharqpur_road'       => __('Lahore - Sharqpur Road', 'woocommerce' ),
            'lahore_sitara_colony'       => __('Lahore - Sitara Colony', 'woocommerce' ),
            'lahore_sukh_chain_garden'   => __('Lahore - Sukh Chain Garden', 'woocommerce' ),
            'lahore_sundar_sharif'       => __('Lahore - Sundar Sharif', 'woocommerce' ),
            // Add more regions as needed
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'region' ));

    // Add new dropdown menu for Block
    woocommerce_form_field( 'block', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide', 'hidden'), // Initially hidden
        'label'         => __('Block'),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => array(
            'block_a'       => __('Block A', 'woocommerce' ),
            'block_b'       => __('Block B', 'woocommerce' ),
            'block_c'       => __('Block C', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'block' ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Add JavaScript to handle conditional display of Block dropdown and update shipping charges
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_fields_script' );
function custom_checkout_fields_script() {
    ?>
    <script type= text/javascript >
        jQuery(function($){
            // Function to show/hide Block dropdown based on Region selection
            $('#region').change(function(){
                var selectedRegion = $(this).val();
                if(selectedRegion == 'lahore_agrics') {
                    $('#block_field').removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $('#block_field').addClass('hidden');
                    $('#block').val(''); // Reset Block dropdown value
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout'); // Trigger WooCommerce update checkout event
                }
            }).change(); // Trigger change event initially

            // Function to update shipping charges based on selected block
            $('#block').change(function(){
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout'); // Trigger WooCommerce update checkout event
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

   
    // Get the selected block
    $selected_block = isset( $_POST['block'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['block'] ) : '';

    // Initialize shipping charges
    $shipping_charges = 0;

    // Set shipping charges based on the selected block
    switch($selected_block) {
        case 'block_a':
            $shipping_charges = 100;
            break;
        case 'block_b':
            $shipping_charges = 150;
            break;
        case 'block_c':
            $shipping_charges = 180;
            break;
        default:
            // No shipping charges by default
            break;
    }

    // Calculate weight-based charges
    $cart_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();
    $extra_weight = $cart_weight - 5; // Get weight exceeding 5 kg
    if ($extra_weight > 0) {
        $extra_charge = $extra_weight * 50; // 50 Rupees per kg for extra weight
        $shipping_charges += $extra_charge;
    }

    // Add shipping charges
    if ( $shipping_charges > 0 ) {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping'), $shipping_charges );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is missing code just after the end of the PHP function that handle your JavaScript...